# HBase and Integration Testing

Tags: python, hbase, integration-testing

I have a Spark project which uses HBase as it's key/value store.  We've started as a whole implementing better CI/CD practices, and I am writing a python client to run integration tests against a self contains AWS environment.

While I am able to easily submit our spark jobs and run them as EMR steps.  I haven't found a good way to interact with HBase from python.  My **goal** is to be able to run our code against sample HDFS data and then verify in HBase that I am getting the results I expected.  Can anyone suggest a good way to do this?


Additionally, my test sets are *very* small.  I'd also be happy if I could simply read the entire HBase table into memory and check it that way.  Would appreciate the communities input.

Comment: Would it be enough for you to connect to HBase DIRECTLY from Python or do you need to connect via Spark? I.e. do you need this in the master code or on the workers? I can give you a quick thrift-based python examples of connecting to Hbase directly, but as far as I can tell there isn't anything out there to connect via Spark per se (due to serialization issues). If you need that, then afraid you'd have to use Jva

Comment: I don't need to connect through Spark.  I would be fine just querying it directly from the Python code.  However there is no connector and using CLI calls seems clunky and unmanageable.

Comment: Okay, putting minimum sample code in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to read HBase data from Python using Happybase API and Thrift Server.

To start thrift server on the Hbase server:

```
/YOUR_HBASE_BIN_DIR/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift
```

Then from Python:

```
import happybase

HOST = 'Hbase server host name here'
TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'
ROW_PREFIX = 'MyPrefix'
COL_TXT = 'CI:BO'.encode('utf-8') # column family CI, column name BO (Text)
COL_LONG = 'CI:BT'.encode('utf-8') # column family CI, column name C (Long)

conn = happybase.Connection(HOST) # uses default port 9095, but provide second arg if non-default port
myTable = conn.table(TABLE_NAME)

for rowID, row in myTable.scan(row_prefix=ROW_PREFIX.encode('utf-8')): # or leave empty if want full table scan
    colValTxt = row[COL_TXT].decode('utf-8')
    colValLong = int.from_bytes(row[COL_LONG], byteorder='big')
    print('Row ID: {}\tColumn Value: {}'.format(rowID, colValTxt))
print('All Done')
```

As discussed in the comment, this won't work if you try to pass things into Spark workers, as the above HBase connection is not serializable. So you can only run this type of code from the master program. If you figure out a way -- share!